# Error trying to install uglify.js on win7

Tags: node.js, windows-7, npm, uglifyjs

I'm trying to make the latest bootstrap version on win7. To do this I'm following directions from http://thomassileo.com/blog/2012/04/21/using-bootstrap-as-a-git-submodule/. I have nodeJS and NPM installed. when I try to run:

```
npm install uglify-js -g
```

I get:

```
$ npm -g install uglify-js
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist/-/optimist-0.3.7.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map
npm ERR! error installing uglify-js@2.2.5    

npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: source-map@'>=0.1.7- <0.2.0-'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.0.0","0.1.0","0.1.1","0.1.2","0.1.3"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\lib\cache.js:488:10)
npm ERR!     at next_ (c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.
js:438:17)
npm ERR!     at next (c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cache.j
s:415:44)
```

Any ideas on what to do next?

Thanks,

Bill

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS

```
UglifyJS is now available through NPM — npm install uglify-js@1 should do the job.

NOTE: The NPM package has been upgraded to UglifyJS2. If you need to install version 1.x 
you need to add `@1` to the command, as I did above. I strongly suggest you to try to
upgrade, though this might not be simple (v2 has a completely different AST structure and API).
```